# Computing the running time of a divide-by-4-and-conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I write this code in python:

```
def sub(ma):
    n = len(ma); m = len(ma[0])
    if n != m : return
    n2 = int(ceil(n/2))
    a = []; b = []; c = []; d = [] 
    for i in range(n2):
        a.append(ma[i][0:n2])
        b.append(ma[i][n2:n])
        c.append(ma[n2+i][0:n2])
        d.append(ma[n2+i][n2:n])
    return [a,b,c,d] 

def sum(ma):
        if len(ma) == 1 : return ma[0][0]
        div = sub(ma)       
        return sum(div[0])+sum(div[1])+sum(div[2])+sum(div[3])
```

Do you know what is a possibly recurrence equation $T(n)$ to the 'sum' method? 
I suppose that is like that
$$T(n) = 4T(n/2) + f(n)$$
what it is $f(n)$ ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subroutine *sub* quarters the matrix into four parts. This takes time $f(n)$, and so the running-time of *sum* (which sums all entries in its input square matrix in a curious divide-and-conquer fashion) satisfies the recurrence
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases} O(1) & n=1 \\ 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 2T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + f(n) + O(1) & n>1. \end{cases} $$
The subroutine *sub* is quite simple, and I'm sure you can figure out its running time yourself (though you'll have to be careful about the semantics of list appending in python).